# Invoke Email to Case and Email Service with One Inbound Email

Tags: contact, apex-email-service, email2case

Based on the documentation, it appears there is no way to simultaneously execute an email service and the email to case standard service.

> When defining email services, note the following: An email service
>   only processes messages it receives at one of its addresses.

Am I missing something or is there some other way to invoke email-to-case and an apex email service at the same time? I would like to create contacts for every inbound email to an email to case email and thought this would be best practice. The documentation example, led me to believe you would want to create task on contacts to signify there is something to action within SF, not within an external system. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_using.htm

If it is not best practice or not an option, I believe my next step would be to utilize a trigger or perhaps a process builder on only during case insert for creating contacts on after inserts of the email-to-case case to extract name and email information from the inbound email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work without issue.

- Suppose your E2C email is `support@mycompany.com`
- The E2C configuration binds this to some SFDC-generated address looking like  `blahblah..na56.salesforce.com`
- If you define an Email Service `foo`, there is a SFDC generated address that looks like `foo....apex.na56.salesforce.com`

Now, in your company's mail server, you set up auto-forwarding such that all mail addressed to `support@mycompany.com` forwards to BOTH `...salesforce.com` addresses.

Comment: I also thought about this, but think rerouting to two service addresses was the equivalent of making two of the same http requests to different endpoints, when they really should just be consumed by one. This seems to be the right answer for using E2C and the Email Service, was hoping for some magic to consume both at one SF service address.